# Сформировать массив, состоящий из тех элементов, которые присутствуют только в одном из массивов

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Пробовал по разному, но всегда на выходе в 3-ем массиве был мусор.

Вот исходник:

```
int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    int size1;
    int size2;
    cout << "Введите размерность первого массива: ";
    cin >> size1;
    cout << "Введите размерность второго массива: ";
    cin >> size2;
    int* arr1 = new int[size1];
    int* arr2 = new int[size2];

    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        cout << "Введите " << i + 1 << " элемент первого массива: ";
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        cout << "Введите " << i + 1 << " элемент второго массива: ";
        cin >> arr2[i];
    }
    cout << "\nПервый массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        cout << arr1[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\nВторой массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        cout << arr2[i] << " ";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то задача состоит в том, чтобы найти элементы первого массива, которых нету во втором массиве, и наоборот.
Для удобства будем использовать вектор:

```
vector <int> answer;
int n;
int size = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
    n = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < size2; x++) {
        if (arr1[i] != arr2[x]) n += 1;
    }
    if (n == size2) {
        size += 1;
        answer.resize(size);
        answer[size - 1] = arr1[i];
    }
}
```

Этот кусок кода проверяет на наличие идентичных элементов первого массива во втором.
Теперь необходимо сделать тоже самое, но для проверки идентичности второго массива:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
    n = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < size1; x++) {
        if (arr2[i] != arr1[x]) n += 1;
    }
    if (n == size1) {
        size += 1;
        answer.resize(size);
        answer[size - 1] = arr2[i];
    }
}
```

Полученный вектор answer содержит искомые элементы.
P.s. знаю, что можно было обойтись и без обратного действия, но в такой простой задаче легче просто пойти "в лоб", как сделал я.